# Constantly changing/inverted color text

Tags: javascript, css, html, text

I want to have text that changes from white with black outline to black with white online constantly and have no idea how to do this.

That's pretty much it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make two css classes with appropriate styles and toggle them on your text using javascript setInterval().

**Example**

*HTML*

```
<div id="container" class="black_white text">
TEXT
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.text {
  font-size: 20px;  
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
}

.black_white {
   color: white;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
}

.white_black {
   color: black;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
}
```

*JS (with jQuery)*

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("#container").toggleClass("black_white");
    $("#container").toggleClass("white_black");
}, 500);
```

Comment: I already have jQuery and css on my site, do I create new ones or just add this?

Comment: Just add this. If you already have jQuery this script will be work.

Comment: Added to the bottom of all three of my files and the text is just black